# Create varying amount of textViews dynamically in android?

Tags: java, android

How can I create a varying amount of `textView`s at run-time depending on a varying `integer` without explicitly instantiating the name of each `textView`?  Each `textView` that is created needs to have a reference because I need to apply `onClickListeners` to each later on.

The code below works just fine, however I have no reference to each `textView` for `onClickListeners`:

```
    private void buildUI(){
    int variable_int = 3; //this variable changes at run-time, set to 3 for this example

for(int i = 1; i <= variable_int; i++){

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(this);

            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText("my textview");

            linLayout.addView(textView);

        }
}
```

A solution I thought of but a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` exception is produce when trying to convert `R.id.box#` to `int` for `findViewById()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    //Create textViews in onCreate(). They are invisible by default
    TextView box1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    TextView box2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box2);
    TextView box3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box3);
    TextView box4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box4);
    TextView box5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box5);

    buildUI();
 }

private void buildUI(){
int variable_int = 3; //this variable changes at run-time, set to 3 for this example

for(int i = 1; i <= variable_int; i++){

            String x = "R.id.box"+i;
            int xx = Integer.parseInt(x); //java.lang.NumberFormatException !

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(xx);

            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText("my textview");

            linLayout.addView(textView);

        }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use RecyclerView or ListView??

Comment: Because I would need to style each row in the ListView according to some other parameters that describe that item. How can this be done in a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps have an array of `TextView`s and then loop over it later.

```
private TextView[] generatedViews;

private void generateViews(int size) {
    this.generatedViews = new TextView[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        ...
        generatedViews[i] = tv;
    }
}

private void assignListeners() {
    for (TextView tv : generatedViews) {
        tv.setOnClickListener(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer. ty

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an event while creating TextView

```
for(int i = 1; i <= variable_int; i++){

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(this);

            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText("my textview");

           **textView.setOnClickListener(....);**

            linLayout.addView(textView);

        }
```